# mysql and tag app structure - alternatives to 'not in' sub select statements

Tags: mysql, tags

While thinking about the best mysql db structure for a web app I'm developing, that requires the use of tags for item classification, I have decided to pick, what seems to be the most common approach: use a tag_map db table between an item table and tag table, for example I have a Clients table and a Tag Table respectively:

```
Example of Clients table:
id,name
0,jack
1,john
2,anna

Example of Tags table:
id,tag
0,likes_oranges
1,likes_cars
2,likes_vacations

Example of tag_map
id,client_id,tag_id
0,0,0 (jack likes oranges)
1,0,1 (jack likes cars)
2,0,2 (jack likes vacations)
3,1,0 (john likes oranges)
4,1,1 (john likes cars)
5,2,1 (anna likes cars)
```

given this distribution, and assuming we the client table can grow above one 1 million rows, my question is:
What is the best approach to query for all customers that *don't* have 'like vacations' tag?

My first choice was to use:

```
select name from clients where id not in (select client_id from tag_map where tags.tag = 'likes vacations')
```

But this query is very slow when the clients and tag_map tables grow above thousand of records.

I have also tried to left join the tag_map to client table, but since all clients have more than one tag assigned, using the *NOT NULL* didn't work either, because I only want to count those who don't have a specific tag id (likes vacations).

Please advise on the best select statement for this type of requirement.

Thanks in advance!

K

Comment: Do you have indexes on client_id and tag_id in the tag_map table?  With proper indexes your query should not degrade that badly.  What's "explain select name from ...." show?

Comment: In fact I was only indexing the ID of the map table. In this case the 'explain select' the Extra column revealed that  only Where clause was being used. I then followed your suggestion and added an new index for both client_id and tag_id. The new 'explain select...' shows that the 'Dependent Subquery' uses the new index, and the response time is very, very fast. Thanks for your help!

Comment: btw, how can I mark your answer/comment as correct?

Comment: you can't accept my comment.  I gave a formal answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to add index on client_id and tag_id in the tag_map table.  Without indexes your query will be very slow with a large number of rows.

Use `explain select ...` to see how the query optimizer is optimizing the query.